# Wraping caught errors

Tags: javascript, typescript, error-handling, try-catch

I cannot find anything on this so I assume I am either searching for the wrong thing or this is not a common thing to do.

I am writing a basic library that abstracts a few underlying libraries. Each underlying library throws its own pretty ambiguous error messages that mean very little to the end user. Some are also extended with different properties.

Currently I catch these errors and throw a new error which makes more sense to the end user and are consistent in structure. However, this loses the stack trace from the original error and I want to preserve this as it contains some information valuable to the end user.

At first I thought a custom Error class was the way to to keep type checking, so I started with something like

```
class WrappedError extends Error {
  readonly stack;

  constructor(message: string, error?: Error) {
    super(message);

    if (error?.stack) {
      this.stack = error.stack
    }
  }
}
```

but quickly realised that even if this works (EDIT: just checked, the trace does not continue) then the `error.stack` would only contain the trace from the original throw to my catch and creation of a new `WrappedError` - everything after would be missing.

This is making me think that my last realistic option is to mutate the original error and rethrow it

```
catch (error) {
  error.message = `Error reason due to such and such, but also; ${error.message}`
  throw error;
}
```

I'm not a massive fan of mutation. And also at this point I quite like the idea of having a single custom error type from my class.

Can stacks be preserved and continued? Or what is the best way to achieve this? Or is there a convention used in JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a [native solution was added](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-error-cause) somewhat recently, so a clean solution would be

```
try {
  ...
} catch (error: unknown) {
  throw new Error('Error reason due to such and such', { cause: error });
}
```